# Unknown column 'startdate' in fieldlist in mysql jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to extract date column '`startdate`' from mysql table named '`course`' but unable to do. It shows unknown column '`startdate`' I am using `jsp` to get the date and print in jsp file. column '`startdate`' is extracted and stored in `java.mysql.Date type`. But still it shows exception. I'm unable to figure out what it is.
The following exception is showed.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
Unknown column 'startdate' in 'field list'
```

Code if as follow

```
   <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
   <%
    Connection con;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to load mySQL driver...");
        return;
    }
    PreparedStatement stat ;
    ResultSet result;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ftk?user=root";    
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    stat = con.prepareStatement("select COUNT(*) from batch  where startdate is NULL and enddate is NULL");
    result = stat.executeQuery();
    result.next();
    int count = result.getInt(1);
    String batchid[] = new String[count];       
    stat = con.prepareStatement("select batchid from batch where startdate is NULL and enddate is NULL");
    result = stat.executeQuery();
    int i=0;
    while(result.next())
    {
        batchid[i++] = result.getString(1);
    }
   %>
    <div id="form" >
    <center>
    <p style="font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:30px;">Generate Schedule</p>
    <form action="scheduleprocess.jsp" method="post">
    <select name = "batchid" required namestyle="width:150px;float:center">
    <%for(i=0; i<count; i++) 
    { 
    %>
    <option  value="<%=batchid[i]%>"><%= batchid[i] %></option>
    <% } 
    %>


       <input type="date" BORDER=5 name="date" value="Date" required>
       <input type="submit" value="Generate">
       </form>
       <%
        if(request.getParameter("schedule")!=null)
        {%>
        <center><script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Batch scheduled successfully! ");
        </script></center>
          </select>
       <p style="font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:30px;">Display Schedule</p>
       <p style="font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:20px;">Phase 1</p>
       <p style="font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:20px;">Foundation Training</p>

       <table style="width:500px">
     <tr style="background-color:grey;">
       <th>CourseID</th>
       <th>Course Name</th>     
       <th>Category</th>
       <th>Start Date</th>
       <th>End Date</th>
     </tr>
        <%
        Statement stmt;
        String coursename,category;
        sdate,edate;
        int courseid,cid;
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        result = stmt.executeQuery("select courseid,coursename,category,startdate,enddate from course where phase=1");
        while(result.next())
        {
            courseid = result.getInt(1);
            coursename = result.getString(2);
            category = result.getString(3);
            sdate = result.getDate(4);
            edate = result.getDate(5);  
            %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= courseid %></td>
       <td><%= coursename %></td>       
       <td><%= category %></td>
       <td><%= sdate %></td>
       <td><%= edate %></td>

     </tr>
      <%
      } 
      %> 

     </table>
     <p style="font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:20px;">Phase 2</p>
       <p style="font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:20px;">Technology Training</p>
       <table style="width:500px">
     <tr style="background-color:grey;">
       <th>CourseID</th>
       <th>Course Name</th>     
       <th>Start Date</th>
       <th>End Date</th>
     </tr>
     <%
        result = stat.executeQuery(); 
        while(result.next())
        {
        courseid = result.getInt(1);
        coursename = result.getString(2);   
        //sdate = result.getDate(4);
        //edate = result.getDate(5);    
        %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= courseid %></td>
       <td><%= coursename %></td>       

     </tr>
      <%
      } 
      %>
     </table>
```

Comment: Does `startdate` also exist in `batch` table? It seems like you are trying to query `batch` table at the beginning using `startdate`.

Comment: Yes initially startdate is NULL. But when the select statement executes startdate field would be inserted with a date.

Comment: huh? I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by 'startdate field would be inserted with a date'. You must have a column named `startdate` in `batch` table for the above code to work. (The data in `startdate` can be null, but the `startdate` column must exist). 

Try running the select query (`select COUNT(*) from batch  where startdate is NULL and enddate is NULL`) on MySQL client and see if that works.

Comment: ya with startdate and enddate NULL it works. startdate field does exist in batch table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of issues in your code due to use of **Scriptlet**

1. Not ending `}` of below `if` block

   ```
   if(request.getParameter("schedule")!=null){
   ```
2. Forget to declare the type of `sdate` and `edate` as shown below

   ```
   sdate,edate;
   ```

It should be `Date sdate,edate;`

---

**Note:** Avoid Scriplets as possible instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) that is easy to use and **less error prone**.

Find more samples here on [JSP - Standard Tag Library (JSTL) Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)